# Question on modelling a sword

Tags: modeling

I'm modelling my first sword for practice, and have a question regarding where the grip meets the guard:

[image]

In this model the grip geometry intersects with the guard and "goes inside" the guard:

[image]

What is the bets thing to do here? Do I just leave it the way it is or should I delete all the internal faces/vertices of the grip and join the guard and grip vertices together to make a mesh without any internal geometry? In terms of UV unwrapping the completely merged mesh would be better but it's a longer modelling process. Appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Loop Tools Add on**

[image]

Image above. 
Top Ortho.  Four stages of Model.

- Cube Scaled with Loop Cuts.
- Remove N by N by 2 Sides vertices
- Loop Tools add on ... Circle .. No hand editing to achieve circle.
- Extrude ...indicated by arrow
- Add more loop cuts and shape to suit needs

User Persp

- Same model showing connectivity and extruded cylinder shape.

[image]

**Shrink Wrap**

[image]

- Shrink Wrap and Apply.
- Blender always has multiple ways to achieve goals.
- 2 Separate objects which can be joined or have parent child relationship
- Above upper right quadrant (Front Ortho View).  Left 2 objects are not visibly connected, gap exists.  Right 2 objects are visibly connected, because  Shrinkwrap modifier has been placed on the bottom vertices of top object.  Bottom vertices are in a vertex group referenced in the Shrink Wrap Modifier.
- User Persp view show details of vertices moved to Nearest Surface point.  No hand editing to move individual vertex points. Vertex Density impacts results.
- You may press the [Apply] button.  You may [Join] two Meshes.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

That would depend on what you intended its use for.

If for the sake of mock up design then either option is fine. I'd recommend trying whichever you're less comfortable with if only to test your ability with blender.

If you intend to break or damage the sword at some later point, then keeping it seperate is more practical.

IF seperate - You should adjust the contours of the grip so that they match the contours of the gaurd (utilizing Edge/Vertex Selection)

[image]

(You should add the tang too(B) if that is the case)[image]