# How Can I Close This Gap Around This Deformed Cylinder?

Tags: modeling, workflow

Nothing I can think of with my experience has worked so far. I need a method to bend the object around the cylinder so that it sticks out slightly (same distance as the very bottom of the dip) all the way around without it losing its shape.

Manually changing it is inaccurate and hard to replicate on the othersides. If anyone has a method that squeezes them together (and the extrusion / spike that comes out the right) that would be awesome.

[image: A cube object with a dip all the way through it and an extrusion out the side placed intersecting a bezier curve / bezier circle combo piece (like a sword handle)]

Comment: Consider [proportional edit].  Also there is a [mirror modifier] ... so you can do less work.  If you choose both sides at once you can move to the center point between them .. the [pivot point].  All these items have tutorials either here ....  Perhaps I understand half of what you wrote.  There is also push pull.  The Blender user interface allows you to find these as well as searching on the menus.   Tutorials will help.

Comment: Perhaps you can demonstrate one edit that did not work .. in a Blender Screen Capture.  The choice is yours.

Comment: Your base could start as a ring or torus shape.  This may allow you to follow the cylinder more easily ... than you can create the other blocky shape or use more than one mesh for the base if it suits you.  You may need more vertices in you base so that in can be formed more easily to the target. Do you have an image of a finished model that you can display in your question?

Comment: Loop Tools is an option ... https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51597/question-on-modelling-a-sword/51605#51605

Comment: do you have a picture of the real object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some Suggestions .. Not a tutorial

**Torus with extrusions, vertex groups, shrink wrap.**

[image]

Here is a low quality facsimile. I will write some simple things and not enough. Loop tools was shown in another link above.

The yellow cylinder.  The turquoise torus which is modified in edit mode.  So clearly the torus allowed fitting to the cylinder more easily. It has enough vertices for a nice fit. [Extrude] was used to produce the giant extrusion to the right. Then [Loop Cut] was performed to add the grid of vertices so that area can be formed.

The red mark on the right show 5 edges meeting like a box corner meeting a floor, produced by extrusion. A ring was selected and a [vertex group] was created.  [Shrink Wrap Modifier] was added with the Cylinder as a target and is depicted above. If you see terms in [] you do not know, you may want to see a tutorial. So now the vertices will conform to the cylinder when they are moved up (grabbed).  [Proportional Edit] is used. One vertex was selected and raised on the z axis. Nearby vertices followed in a smooth edit.

To the left some other vertices were chosen and put in a vertex group.  A shrink wrap modifier was added, with the box as target. This was added to show straightening an area. Clearly you can straighten an area in many different ways.  Note the red mark on the left where 4 edges meet.  To show a modelling [error], an extrusion was not used.  You can see the diamond shape stretched which you might not want.  No loop cuts were used, just to identify areas.  You may only need on shrink wrap.

I left big gaps in the visual .. you can reduce the gaps.  Please inspect and correct and optimize this work.  You can do better work than this.

Finally one area scaled.  Vertex group created on side and a Shrink Wrap.  You can press [apply] for modifiers.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help, I did what you suggested and it turned out great, Will be using it again on another part of my model

Comment: If you think this is an answer please select it as an answer.  You may also cast a negative vote if you do not like the answer.